# Looking for a macro that can manipulate the compiler's optimization feature

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

Is there a way to mark a block of code or a function as an excluded part of the compiler's optimization feature?

I have a bug that occur only when the optimization feature is on. I have some guesses about where it might be, and this macro can be a nice help.

Comment: Sure: `#if 0 ... #endif`

Comment: the first idea that comes to my mind is "use the extern keyword" and manage the linkage of this "special" functions in a next step.

Comment: [may be useful](http://cache.freescale.com/files/dsp/doc/app_note/AN3674.pdf)

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why you want this? I can hardly imagine a scenario where that might be useful.

Comment: The standard use case is when the code seems to work in debug mode, but crashes in release mode. In 99.9% of these cases there is a bug in the program, not in the compiler.

Comment: Could be a missed sequence point, BTW. Or an int function without a return statement, returning the right stuff by incidence ("pseudo tail recursion") Or uninitialised variables. Or a memory overwrite. Or any kind of UB.

Comment: BTW: why is "kernel" in the tags? *shudder* BTW: I actually like the idea of "binary search" to pinpoint a problem. Agreed: it is a course way, by it is certainly analytics for engineers (like swapping the tires to find out which one is flat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gcc, you can use the `optimize` pragma at function level to avoid optimizations.

**[#pragma GCC optimize "O0"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)** can be applied for a function to prevent optimizations of that function. But I am not sure if there's a way to prevent a *block* of code being optimized.

So you can have an overall optimization setting for the whole program and this will override that setting with the given optimization for a function using `optimize`.

Answer (score 4):

I would be VERY worried if I see code that has `#pragma GCC optimize "O0"` in it. I'd ***definitely*** require anyone working with me to make a very clear comment as to why that is necessary, and probably report the compiler bug that is the reason why it's not working with optimization to the compiler vendor.

And if you even ***thought*** about submitting something to a kernel mailing list or some such, I'd ensure wearing tripple or quadruple layers of asbestos, because the flames coming your way will be intense.

The right thing to do is figure out a workaround as to why your code isn't compiling correctly with optimisation on. There is probably something wrong with your code if you need this - typically that it relies on "how you think the compiler does something", which doesn't happen when you optimize the code. That's bad coding, and should definitely not be solved by disabling the compilers optimization.

Comment: Maybe it is for debugging local function... But I am fully agree with your comment

Comment: Debugging or not, the code should work when compiled. I don't think, in the last 17 years, that I've ever had code "not work" in all levels of optimization [at least not code I've worked on professionally]. But of course, I have seen the odd compiler bug that requires tweaking of the compiler flags or tweaking the code  to "avoid".

Comment: I was just saying that it is easier to debug (with gdb) a function not optimized (step by step, ...)

Comment: Yes, so recompile the whole thing to -O0. If the bug goes away, then you need to figure out what is different, and that can indeed be tricky. I usually resort to "printf" debugging at that point, or checking the assembler code, etc.